# Convert plain text to CSV

Tags: python, csv

My source file which contains 5000 rows is as below,

```
1.4.1 This is my text and is not limited to three words 3 ALL ALL
1.4.2 This is second sentence 1 ALL ALL
1.4.3 An another sentence that I just made up 2 ALL ALL
```

I want to search and replace (or any other method) to produce the output below

```
"1.4.1", "This is my text and is not limited to three words", "3", "ALL", "ALL"
"1.4.2","This is second sentence","1","ALL","ALL"
"1.4.3", "An another sentence that I just made up","2","ALL", "ALL"
```

The sentence that I would like in the 2nd column is of varying length but is always between two numbers - 1.4.1 and 3 for example. This is a complicated part that I am trying to figure out how to achieve.

Edit:
The last two columns are optional, may or may not appear on all lines

```
"1.4.1", "This is my text and is not limited to three words", "3"
```

Comment: Why don't you split each line at the spaces, take the first part from the left, 3 parts from the right, and join the rest again to one string?

Answer (score 1):

This can actually be fairly simple assuming all columns but the 2nd one will never contain a space. You can simply split the entire string and pull out the necessary parts as below:

```
[ 1.4.1, This, is, my, text, and, is, not, ,limited, ,to, three, ,words, 3, ALL, ALL ]
  +---+ +-------------------------------------------------------------+  +  +-+  +-+
    1st                                2nd                              3rd 4th  5th
```

Once the full line is split like above, you can simply access the proper elements for the one word / number columns and join the 2nd column elements. Below is a simple python function that should accomplish what you are looking to do:

```py
def parse_record(line):
    parts = line.split()

    col_1 = parts[0]
    col_2 = " ".join(parts[0: -3])
    col_3 = parts[-3]
    col_4 = parts[-2]
    col_5 = parts[-1]

    return col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5
```

If you have control over the file format this becomes much simpler actually. If you are able to change the way the 2nd column is specified, it is technically already a csv. Most csv parsers allow you to specify the delimiter between values, in this case a space. For example if the same  file above would quote the  2nd column like this:

```
1.4.1 "This is my text and is not limited to three words" 3 ALL ALL
1.4.2 "This is second sentence" 1 ALL ALL
1.4.3 "An another sentence that I just made up" 2 ALL ALL
```

Since the 2nd column's values are wrapped in quotes they will be parsed as a single value rather than many separate ones, allowing you to simply use a space as the csv delimiter rather than the default  comma.